# iOS Cloudy UIViewController Background

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create my first iOS app using Swift and Xcode 7.2. I am using SpriteKit to make Tetris. After the user loses, the view switches from a UIViewController with a SKScene inside it, in which the game runs, to a UIViewController that is a death screen saying the user's score and their high score. I was wondering if there is a way to have a background on the death screen have a translucent background so that the user sees the game they just played in the background. Any help would be great. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the UIViewController of your game, you can add a SubView with a blur effect: http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-blur-effect-ios8-swift

Your view need to have a smaller zPosition than your "game over button" for exemple. So when the game is over, you add the "blurred view" and on it you add your other things like the score label. When the user restart the game you just need to remove the view and restart your game.